# Issue with goroutine and Waitgroup

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to iterate a loop and call go routine on an anonymous function and adding a waitgroup on each iteration. And passing a string to same anonymous function and appending the value to slice **a**. Since I am looping 10000 times length of the slice is expected to be 10000. But I see random numbers. Not sure what is the issue. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Here is my code snippet

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
func main() {
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    var a []string
    for i := 0; i <= 10000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(s string) {

            a = append(a, s)
            wg.Done()
        }("MaxPayne")
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(len(a))
}
```

Comment: As a hint: try running [`go run -race .`](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how appending a slice, you actually make a new slice, and then assign it back to the slice variable. So you have un-controlled concurrent writing to the variable `a`. Concurrent writing to the same value is not safe in Go (and most languages). In order to make it safe, you can serialize the writes with a mutex.

Try:

```golang
var lock sync.Mutex
var a []string
```

and

```golang
lock.Lock()
a = append(a, s)
lock.Unlock()
```

For more information about how a mutex works, see the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) and the [sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) package.

Here is a pattern to achieve a similar result, but without needing a mutex and still being safe.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const sliceSize = 10000

    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)

    var a = make([]string, sliceSize)

    for i := 0; i < sliceSize; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(s string, index int) {
            a[index] = s
            wg.Done()
        }("MaxPayne", i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

This isn't exactly the same as your other program, but here's what it does.

1. Create a slice that already has the desired size of 10,000 (each element is an empty string at this point)
2. For each number 0...9999, create a new goroutine that is given a specific index to write a specific string into
3. After all goroutines have exited and the waitgroup is done waiting, then we know that each index of the slice has successfully been filled.

The memory access is now safe even without a mutex, because each goroutine is only writing to it's respective index (and each goroutine gets a unique index). Therefore, none of these concurrent memory writes conflict with each other. After initially creating the slice with the desired size, the variable `a` itself doesn't need to be assigned to again, so the original memory race is eliminated.

Comment: Thank you so much worked like a charm.. one question But using lock makes it sequential right ?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true. The lock serializes the access, meaning that only one goroutine can append at a time. It's simply not safe for multiple goroutines to append at once, as each append requires that goroutine to modify the `a` variable each time. I'll update the answer to show a pattern that can do a similar thing without serialization.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. Will be waiting for your updated code